# Generating JSON schema in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json.net

As part of my WCF service, I return SQL query result as Json using JavaScriptSerializer. I want to be able to provide schema of JSON as an output and looking for some feedback on how to achieve this.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
}
return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

Comment: You want to auto-generate a JSON schema based on the results of a SQL query?  For example if you add a new column to your SQL table you want that to be immediately reflected in the output of your schema-generator?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no built-in library that does that; however, there are a few samples (including [this one which I wrote](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Web-API-to-convert-a-JSON-0a13f21b)) which parses JSON into a structure which is then converted into a series of classes following the JSON "schema". The main issue with the algorithm is to "merge" objects in arrays, making sure that if you have something like

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"c":4}]
```

It would generate a class with the int members `a`, `b` and `c`.

The file JsonRoot.cs in the sample has most of the code for parsing the JSON into the "schema" structure. From there you can export that into whichever format you want (the sample itself exports it as C# or VB classes).